# Minor tweaks in story based agile/iterative development

Tags: agile, user-stories, tweak

What is the preferred way to treat tiny interface tweaks such as "make the menu colour lighter when you hover over it" when using stories.

My first though was to treat it as a bug; stick it on an index card and add it to the bugs file for scheduling into an up-coming iteration.

I just wondered if anyone else had any alternatives that they would recommend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a lot of those small interface tweaks, you could make them tasks within an overall "improve GUI" user story. Of course that overall story should have a certain business value (easier navigation) and have a good description "as a user I want to... in order to.. ".

Comment: +1: "Wrap" the tweaks in a generic "As a user..." story may help prioritize the value.  Or, it may be a silly level of formality.  It's pretty clear what this generic story is, so just inserting the task as a bare "do this" should work out fine.   No one should be confused in seeing a task among the stories.

Answer (score 3):

They are a **user story like any other.**

If it's a single, trivial UI tweak, **it can be a cheap user story** - but I'd still **represent it as a story so that it's taken into account in velocity, estimation and planning**.

If you want to collect a bunch of small UI tweaks on the same thing - e.g. slightly different colour text for a div tag and a different font family, then by all means group them together into a bigger user story - so long as the description of the user story makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a requested feature then i would create a new story for it for the next sprint/iteration. "Implement Visual Feedback for User Interaction via Pointer Device with the Page Selection Module" sounds like a nice story for that... or simply "UI Layout Enhancements" to group several of such small tweaks together.